# Is it possible to search Solspace Calendar dates with Supersearch

Tags: solspace-calendar, supersearch

I'm using Solspace's Calendar module to assign multiple dates to entries and I need the option to search through these entries by date using the Solspace Supersearch module, i've not come accross any docs on this. If I look at the field in the exp_channel_data table its just assigning the id of the calendar being used.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out-of-the-box, but there is a workaround:

Depending on how exactly you plan to search for Calendar events, you could use the [Solspace Preparse add-on](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/preparse). What you could do is create a new field that is used to parse the calendar data in a plain string text value (you could format the date however you please).

The Preparse field will populate data (in this case from Calendar) after you publish/update the entry, and insert whatever data you've told it to (using a regular EE template) back into your Preparse field for the entry. That would mean you then have a field that is searchable by Super Search. :)

You could then attempt to run a range (from/to) search on it in your search form.

Comment: Great thanks a lot for that and for getting back so quickly. It would be useful if you could provide this info in the Supersearch docs.